# How to fairly assign bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I have a question with bounty here [Reverse proxy to put header value as parameter to url](https://superuser.com/questions/902083/reverse-proxy-to-put-header-value-as-parameter-to-url) with two answers. Each answer seems to me to be solution of 1/2 of my question. Is it possible to split bounty between both answers ? How can I choose to be fair and not discourage someone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bounty can only be assigned to one user. It's up to you to choose which answer you think deserves the bounty. If you think both answers are equally good, you have two choices:

- Choose an answer to reward randomly, by flipping a coin or something like that...
- Or, award the bounty to one answer, then start a new bounty to reward the other answer.

If both answers are equally excellent to you, you might also consider which user already has less/more reputation and might benefit from the bounty.

Comment: Ok, I will put bounty to the one with less reputation.